# How to avoid values turning to a Scientific format when text contains 'E' followed by a number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, text-formatting

I am trying to open an excel file that has a column containing different barcodes. These barcodes have the following format:

```
4820001E1
4820001E2
4820002E1
4820002E2
```

However, when I open the file, the column changes to a scientific format and I cannot revert it to the format above.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Format your row/column as Text **before** copy/pasting your data into it. Then paste into the data entry line, not the cell itself.
If you paste to the cell it will [stupidly] re-format to Scientific. You can Paste Special [as Text], but that's more effort than just pasting to the data entry line.

[image]

Left column formatted as General, with first data entry 'converted' back to text - doesn't work.
Right column formatted as Text **first**.

[image]

Comment: how can i paste into the data entry line? It doesn't allow me to do that. Also paste special (as text) doesn't work

Comment: I have no idea why either of those might happen. The data entry line is for… entering data. That's its sole purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In a new Excel 365 there is a special option to disable this feature.
[Automatic Data Conversion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/what-s-new-in-excel-october-2023/ba-p/3945988)
[image: Automatic Data Conversion]